# src absolute path problem

Tags: html, image, src, absolute-path

I have an image in **C:\wamp\www\site\img** and i try to display it in a page with this:

```
<img src="C:\wamp\www\site\img\mypicture.jpg"/>
```

but it's not working.The file is actually there and if I try to refer to it with a relative path i got the picture

```
<img src="../img/mypicture.jpg">
```

where is the error?what am I missing??
thank you again guys!

Comment: `<img src="C:\\wamp\\www\\site\\img\\mypicture.jpg"/>` maybe will work if on same machine

Comment: @kjy112 No. See @Luke's answer.

Comment: @rlb.usa if it's on same local machine it should work.

Comment: I'm COMPLETELY new to programming and web design. Got here for I had the same problem that stated in the question. I had the image in another disk other than C, so it did not work.-
After some research, and taking a look at the adress bar, I noticed some extra slashes, and now I can see the image where it's supposed to be.- Just in case someone might find it useful: <IMG SRC="file:///D:/img/smiley.gif"> Oh, by the way, I guess there is not a 'localhost' for I am not using one, the html file is on same disk, but it's not -yet- on a server(He, have no idea how to do it! =D).- Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be referencing it as `localhost`. Like this:

`<img src="http:\\localhost\site\img\mypicture.jpg"/>`

Comment: thanks i used your suggestion but with forward slashes and now i have my image..but i was wondering why for example my css referenced with "c:\wamp\www\site\css\mycss.css" works instead??

Comment: Never use backward slashes in urls

Comment: (late comment, i know) Simply because the protocol is wrong, there is no `C:` protocol. You could have used the `file://` protocol instead if you really wanted to (not necessarily `http://`localhost), and yes, no backward slashes as leonbloy said

Comment: is there any way i could catch or know that image is broken?

Comment: @MuneemHabib See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Answer (score 14):

`<img src="file://C:/wamp/www/site/img/mypicture.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 12):

I think because C would be seen the C drive on the client pc, it wont let you.  And if it could do this, it would be a big security hole.

Comment: what do you mean? explain please

Comment: If you reference things from C drive; for one the file would need to be located in the same location on everyone's pc.  I'm not saying that what you want to do was a big hole, but imaging if you were able to start up command prompt, by linking to it via the C root.

Comment: I got it Luke thanks!now I was wondering why i didn't encounter the same problem with my css file referenced the same using my "C drive"

Comment: You might have to do some research on that, but I think it has something to do with how the page is rendered, objects defined in the header section are rendered pre the page load, so although you are asking for c:\xxx.css it is actually being found as if on the server, am waffling might not be even close :).  I have another suggestion, if you want to have absolute links you can reference your images via from the root of your IIS by the following: `src="/site/img/mypicture.jpg"`

Answer (score 2):

Use forward slashes.
See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358034/relative-image-path-not-showing-image-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

First open the image in any web browser. Then copy the path and add it as image source location like this :

```
src="file:///C:/wamp64/www/site/img/mypicture.jpg"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: File path should be relative path which doesn't include drive path.