# How do i change image src using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to change an image src which is jsp page through jquery. my code is right below

```
$('#image').attr("src","file:///D:/vow/themes/multiflex/webapp/multiflex/images/chart.png");
```

In JSP File I Have

```
<table>
<tr style="padding-bottom:5px;">
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Image &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;<img id="image"/></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But i see no display on my jsp page after i run.I have my source code and image are in different directories.

Comment: Post the rest of the code

Comment: instead of "file://..", use the url like "http://www.somesite.com/../chart.png"

Comment: My guess is that your browser is denying access to your local hard drive, but we'd have to see your whole piece of code to know for sure.

Comment: Does your code and image are on different drives?

Comment: Yes .. my code and image are on different drives

Answer (score 1):

I think because D would be seen the D drive on the client pc, it wont let you. And if it could do this, it would be a big security hole.

See below link

[src absolute path problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157772/src-absolute-path-problem)

Try relative path like

```
$("#image").attr("src", "/images/chart.png");
```

Answer (score -2):

you use src attribute, try specifying the src with the image to identify it on a html page:

`$('img[src="your-current-image-src"]').attr('src','your-new-src');`

and make sure 'file:///' wont work you need some sort of url or relative path

Comment: The last paragraph is correct, but the idea to change the selector is utterly wrong.

Comment: also note that file-URLs _are_ "some sort of url" and the asker is unlikely to understand "relative path" - an example of a valid URL?