# how do I load an image from parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I am having trouble loading my images from parse.com. I have my link to my file, but the output I keep getting is [picture image]. I am currently trying to display the parse image file as the normal html way `<src = "filepath...` so on and so forth.

Could I get some insight on where I need to be looking? Does it require that I do a checksum or anything?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried? Some code to look at?

Comment: Have a look here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157772/src-absolute-path-problem.