# Using JavaScript script multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't believe this has been asked before. If it has I apologise as I couldn't find it.

I have an HTML table with pictures as buttons:

```
<td>
  <button class="trigger">
    <img src="D:\Elly Research\ CO2858\Presentation\Calypso_map.jpg">
  </button>
</td>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times; </span>
    <img src="D:\Elly Research\CO2858\Presentation\Calypso_map.jpg">
    <script src="D:\Elly Research\CO2858\Presentation\modal.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is controlled by a script:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector (".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
  modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if(event.target === modal){
    toggleModal();
  }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

If I copy the format of the first picture and use it for a second picture in the same table and same page, it stops working.

Does JavaScript not work like CSS where I can use multiple ID's to be controlled by one CSS value?

This is the first time I've used JavaScript with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you please paste the whole HTML/JS? Maybe in CodePen?

Comment: What "stops working"? Please describe the expected behavior and the observed behavior. Screenshots can help too!

Comment: apologies, i want the pictures to popup when clicked on, the script works on the first picture only. I would of thought if i copied the code to the second picture then it would make that picture popup but it doesnt....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to ask. Based on my assumptions here is a small snippet. Hope it helps you.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal")
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
document.querySelector(".close-button").addEventListener("click", toggleModal)

function showImage(event){
 toggleModal()
  modal.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src =event.srcElement.src
}

function windowOnClick(event){
  if(event.srcElement === modal){
    toggleModal()
  }
}

function toggleModal(){
  modal.classList.toggle("show-modal")
}
```

```css
td > img{
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.modal{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index=10;
}

.show-modal{
  display: block !important;
}

.modal-content{
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.close-button{
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#viewer{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GV6086A.jpg" onclick="showImage(event)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/opERcp1.jpg" onclick="showImage(event)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lieUEvQ.jpg" onclick="showImage(event)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/B63gaEQ.jpg" onclick="showImage(event)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <span class="close-button">&times; </span>
        <img id="viewer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted thank you! i just need to put that into my code, you are a god send i need this for tomorrow morning lol thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do `document.querySelector(".modal")` you are selecting the first node that has the class "modal". Which in your case would be the div containing the first picture. And later you add the `'click'` event to only the first picture.

You can use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of all the matching nodes and loop through all nodes to add the `'click'` event listener like so:

```
const modals = document.querySelector(".modal");

modals.forEach(modal => {
    modal.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
});
```

Comment: Or a delegated event listener.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small application, a simple solution to this could be the creation of an object of images, containing its details, like this:
    
    `//Here you can add as many properties you want for the objects
    images = [{
        src: "D:\Elly Research\CO2858\Presentation\Calypso_map.jpg"
    },
    {
        src: "D:\Elly Research\CO2858\Presentation\Calypso_map_alternative.jpg"
    }]`

Then you could iterate over it to generate your table, or simply create your table with some ID refs, like `<button id="0" class="trigger">`, therefore you can access them in the event object array index with this code:

```
var id = event.target.id
```

So, to generate the img element inside the modal, you'll have something like this:
    `function toggleModal(event){
        var id = event.target.id;
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-content')[0];
        div.innerHTML += '<img class="modal-image" src="'+images[id].src+'" />'; 
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }`

But make sure you destroy the img element when it already have one:

```
var child = div.querySelector("img");
if(child != null){
    div.removeChild(child);
}
```

Hope it helps you!! Good luck with your study!

Answer (score 0):

You can use js multiple times. Check the src of your images.
It's discussed already here -[src absolute path problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157772/src-absolute-path-problem).