# Add image in html with full path

Tags: html, image

I try to add image in html with full path. I google the problem and found this [src absolute path problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157772/src-absolute-path-problem) and I try every answer, but does not work for me.

This is my code, do you have any idea, why image is not found?

```
<img src="file://C:/Storage/Images/a.png" alt="las vegas" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Too little slashes - you need one more  file:/// or if the html file is in the storage folder, use `"Images/a.png"`

Comment: Storage folder is random folder with that name, you mean like this file:///C://Storage//Images//a.png?

Comment: @RobinchoBibanka I think he means `file:///C:/Storage/Images/a.png` (but don't know exactly, but I am pretty sure there isn't any `//` in file path but `/` yes) and `file` need `///` like he tell you mplungjan

Comment: @Laaouatni Anas Does not work again

Comment: I meant `file:///C:/Storage/Images/a.png` OR `Images/a.png` - the last is relative to the html file

Comment: What is the URL of the HTML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open the folder explorer

[image]

2. click **right-click** on the image in the file explorer

    you will see a dropdown with some buttons
3. click the `"copy path"`

[image]

4. now we need to add the link to the `src` attribute
5. write `file:///` (3 slash `/`)
6. paste the copied path after `file:///`

```
file:///"C:\Users\laaou\Downloads\1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png"
```

7. delete the `"` character at the start and at the end `"`

```
file:///C:\Users\laaou\Downloads\1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png
```

8. like he said **@mplungjan** change the `\` to `/` (see his first comment)

> you can use an online tool like this http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/replace-text/ (if you have long links)

9. here is the final HTML

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/laaou/Downloads/1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png">
```

---

### alternative ways

but still better to put the images in the same folder where there is the `index.html`

so you just need to write

1. `./imageName.png`
2. or `./MyFolder/imageName.png`

---

or host your image in a service like `Imgur`

and write that link inside the `src`

the link it will be like this: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRUS3.png`

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRUS3.png">
```

Comment: and change all `\ ` to  `/` and all spaces to `%20` or `+`

Comment: For some reason, I dont know why this work in html file, but in jsp file does not work. Maybe I will just stored it in the index.html folder

Comment: @RobinchoBibanka good, is better inside the same folder so you can use `./RelativePath/myImage.jpg` (`.` dot means this folder)